# Specify PostgreSQL Schema in Django

Tags: django, postgresql

I am trying to build some DB front-ends using Django since I like the general MVC structure as well as their template system and admin interface. However, I am having trouble with certain aspects of using a PostgreSQL back-end.

I've managed to figure out how to specify different schemas (and databases) using the database section of the `settings.py` file like so:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    },
    'MPS': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'options': '-c search_path=django'
        },
       'NAME': 'sandbox_manzer',
       'HOST': '192.168.2.151',
       'PORT': '5434',
       'USER': '******',
       'PASSWORD': '**********************',
    }
}
```

However, when I try and script some basic tests, as detailed [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/tutorial05/), I run into a problem.  My user can create databases just fine so my test_db gets built, but when the django app goes to build the models into tables I get an error stating that `No schema is specified` for the test_db.  Any help in how I specify schema names for the test_db would be most appreciated.  Especially since I intend to build out multiple apps for a single project using different schemas as logical separators.

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I suppose you are familiar with the concept of PostgreSQL [schemas.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/ddl-schemas.html)

Your app is looking for the `django` schema in your database (which presumably isn’t there) because you have specifically told it so.

```
       'options': '-c search_path=django'
```

For each application, create a suitably named schema and specify it in the `search_path`.

Comment: Thanks Dario.  However, I am not sure how to affect this in the test_db (which is where this problem is occurring).  As I think you know the test_db is created anew and then destroyed when running Django tests.  I cannot find any documentation on how to specify an existing database for testing purposes. Perhaps using the `MIRROR` shown [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/testing/advanced/#controlling-creation-order-for-test-databases) could be useful.  Any thoughts?

Comment: My first try would be to specify `search_path=django,public`, so that tables should be created in `public` (which is always there) if `django` doesn’t exist; alternatively, you might comment out the whole `OPTIONS` section, but you would lose the benefit of having separate schemas.

Comment: I am trying to avoid loading everything into the public schema.  I've read a few papers suggesting that bloating the public schema can interfere with PostgreSQL server operations and possibly cause performance issues.  Also I wanted to use schemas as logical separators for my different apps.  I will continue to play around with this.

Comment: Django 1.11: `OperationalError: ERROR:  unsupported startup parameter: options`

Comment: @Matt - same for Django 3.2. Have you found the decision ?