# Django raw query "Schema does not exists"

Tags: python, django, django-1.7

I'm using django 1.7, and I wish to make us a Count with a conditional. This is possible in django 1.8 onwards, but I'm unable to upgrade. As such, I'm trying to write a raw query as detailed in [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33777815/7052826). Regretfully, I haven't yet managed.

**My query:**

```
a = Photo.objects.raw(
'select "photos_photo"."id" , '
'COUNT('
'DISTINCT '
'CASE '
'WHEN "point_substanceexistslabel"."substance"."name" = "fabric" then 1 else null end) as c '
'FROM "photos_photo" '
'LEFT OUTER JOIN "points_substanceexistslabel"  '
'on ("photos_photo"."id" =  "points_substanceexistslabel"."photo_id")'
' GROUP BY "photos_photo"."id"'
)
```

Running the query and trying to print a result raised the following error:

```
ProgrammingError: schema "point_substanceexistslabel" does not exist
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Specify PostgreSQL Schema in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41452195/specify-postgresql-schema-in-django)

Comment: Show us your table structure (or models). You cannot have `"point_substanceexistslabel"."substance"."name"`, in your SQL query, that's indeed the format _schema.table.column_ so Postgres is trying to match `point_substanceexistslabel` to a schema, not a table.

Comment: Are you sure you can't express this query via the ORM? There doesn't seem to be anything particularly complicated in it.

Comment: @DanielRoseman The `case` and `when` are introduced in django 1.8